# How do I access Jinja2 for loop variables outside the loop?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template page which contains two separate `{% for %}` loops. If neither of these loops contain any items, I want the page to redirect.

I'm trying to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
loop1 = loop.length (in first loop)
loop2 = loop.length (in second loop)

if loop1 + loop2 == 0: redirect # (outside both loops)
```

Is this even possible? Is there a way to make the `loop.length` variables available outside their respective loops?

Comment: err.. the redirect needs to come from the server and nothing to do with templates.

Comment: try *first loop* `{% set i = loop.counter0 %}`  *second loop* `{% set j = loop.counter0 %}`  *condition* `{% if i+j equals 0 %}`

Comment: That's what I tried first, but i and j don't exist outside their respective loops.

Comment: Each loop puts a div on the page each time it iterates, and these divs share a class, text, etc that is found nowhere else. Is there a way to simply, after both loops have run, say, "if this class or text does not exist on the page, redirect" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your lists for truth, empty lists are false in Jinja2.

```
{% if things %}
    {% for thing in things %} .... {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <!-- redirect here -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I'm filtering the for condition, so it's actually

{% for thing in things if not thing.attribute %}


So how do I test if "things if not thing.attribute" is true?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "no": You can't re-direct using a template -- it should be in the view logic of the controller/server.

Although technically one can, but not doing anyone any favours.

Comment: I realize that, but in this case I have no choice, the project (hopefully) won't require this for very long, and it was decided that doing it this way will be easier than changing things on the backend.

Comment: then you just proxy re-direct rules in the middle -- sounds like a horrible way to do so though

Comment: @DsDyer: then you should ask the person who decided it was easy to write the code, and disprove everyone who asserts that it's not, in fact, easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both things are lists, you can do this:

```
{% set all_things = thing1 + thing2 %}
{% if all_things %}
    {# There is more than one thing in the two lists #}
{% else %}
    {# redirect #}
```

That being said, this is **not** something that belongs at the template level - you are generating another list containing all of the things in `thing1` and `thing2` every time you hit the page, which will cost in terms of resources. You are putting application logic in the template level, which will not be maintainable.  And finally, you are papering over the larger problem - that making changes to the back end code is costly.  (Please understand that "you" in all these cases is the generic "you" - as in "the company you work for").

You (specifically) should raise these issues with those who are asking you to implement this hack and try to change the direction that this tool / product / company is taking before it becomes a piece of FrankenCode.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length `things` object(the object you are looping through) by using the [length filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length):

```
{{things|length}}
```

Now to answer your question. lets assume the objects you loop through is named `t1` and `t2`, you could do:

```
{% if t1 | length == 0 and t2 | length == 0 %}
 //use javascript to redirect(assuming you have the link)
{% endif %}
```

You could do this in your JavaScript block. I do not know if this is the most efficient way to do it, but, it should work.

I am posting this answer, because there is no up-voted or accepted answer to this question.
I do Hope this helps.