# How can i access a jinja2 variable outside the for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

im trying to use a for loop to add up some numbers for each day
and i would like to access the variable outside the for loop  im not sure how to go about this   I am using the flask framework with python  and just come from weppy where this was not a problem  is there a way to make it work the same way in flask?

here is some simple code

```
{% set newtotal = 0 %}
{% for item in daily: %}
    {% set newtotal = newtotal + item[10]|float %}
{% endfor %}

<div class="bottom">
    <span>Total: {{ newtotal }}</span>
</div>
```

the numbers collected by item[10] are dollar values
if i place the `{{ newtotal }}` before the endfor it shows every value as its being added up this is not what I want

**EDIT**:
if it helps daily is a list of 8 tuples

Comment: Can you pass in a variable named "newtotal" that is equal to the `len(daily)` (that you would calculate in your Python server script)?

Comment: this is basically what i ended up doing  thats for the hint ;)

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that it is not possible to set variables inside a block or loop and have them show up outside of it.
As of version 2.10 this can be handled using namespace objects which allow propagating of changes across scopes.

Here is your code using namespace:

```
{% set ns = namespace (newtotal = 0) %}
{% for item in daily: %}
    {% set ns.newtotal = ns.newtotal + item[10]|float %}

{% endfor %}

<div class="bottom">
    <span>Total: {{ ns.newtotal }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution (probably the "simplest") would be to change your Python script to pass in a variable named newtotal that would simply be the length of the `daily` list!

Alternatively, you could use the [length filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length):

```
{{things|length}}
```

In which case your code could look something like this:

```
{% set newtotal = 0 %}
{% for item in daily: %}
    {% set newtotal = newtotal + item[10]|float %}
{% endfor %}

<div class="bottom">
    <span>Total: {{daily|length}}</span>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Additional Sources:

[jinja2: get lengths of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465249/jinja2-get-lengths-of-list)

[How do I access Jinja2 for loop variables outside the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728332/how-do-i-access-jinja2-for-loop-variables-outside-the-loop)

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misread the question!

You can use the [sum filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sum) instead (`{{ list | sum() }}`).

So your code could look like:

```
{% set newtotal = 0 %}
{% for item in daily: %}
    {% set newtotal = newtotal + item[10]|float %}
{% endfor %}

<div class="bottom">
    <span>Total: {{ daily | sum() }}</span>
</div>
```

New sources:

[Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sum)
[Sum elements of the list in Jinja 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525101/sum-elements-of-the-list-in-jinja-2)

Comment: when i do this it just returns the length of the list not a sum of the items in position 10

Comment: I edited the answer, hope it works, it seems to have worked for other people on SO!

Answer (score 1):

Use the namespace object.

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#assignments

Here’s a working example from my config.

```
{% set i= namespace(fxp0_ip=0) %}
{% set i= namespace(mgmt_ip = 0) %}
{% set i= namespace(loopback_ip = 0) %}
{% set i= namespace(lan_ip = 0) %}
{% set i= namespace(wan_ip = 0) %}
{% for interface in device_vars.interfaces %}
    {% elif interface.name == "ge-0/0/0" %}
       {% set i.mgmt_ip = interface.ip_addr %}
    {% elif interface.name == "lo0" %}   
       {% set i.loopback_ip = interface.ip_addr %}
    {% elif interface.name == "ge-0/0/2" %}   
       {% set i.lan_ip = interface.ip_addr %}
    {% elif interface.name == "ge-0/0/1" %}   
       {% set i.wan_ip = interface.ip_addr %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


{{i.mgmt_ip}}

{{i.wan_ip}}
```